# List comprehension for reading lists of integers

Tags: python, python-3.x

As of reading the following `input.txt` file:

```
1 6 14
1 2 7
1 3 9
2 3 10
2 4 15
3 6 2
3 4 11
4 5 6
5 6 9
```

I wanted to make a list of lists containing each line as a list of integers

```
[[1, 6, 14],
 [1, 2, 7],
 [1, 3, 9],
 ...
 [5, 6, 9]]
```

I achieved that by doing the following

```
with open('input.txt', 'r') as f:
    # gets lines as list of strings [['1, 2, 3,', ...]]     
    nodes_list = [n.split() for n in f.readlines()] 
    # convert strings inside the lists to int's [[1, 2, 3], ...]
    nodes_list = [[int(y[0]), int(y[1]), int(y[2])] for y in nodes_list]
```

Is there any way that I can achieve the same with a single comprehension list, without the need of having two separated ones? If not, maybe some cleaner way of doing it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about:

```
with open('input.txt', 'r') as f:  
    nodes_list = [[int(item) for item in line.split()] for line in f]
```

Notice how:

1. rather than iterating over `f.readlines()`, which creates a list of the lines in the file, we iterate over `f`, which produces the same result, but as a generator,
2. rather than first creating a potentially huge list of lists of strings, then converting it to a list of lists of ints, only a single row is instantiated at a time.

Comment: I would also add, that `[int(item) for ...]` is easier to read than `list(map(int, ...))`

Comment: Have to apologize to @mleyfman, but your answer is more clear and concise. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a `map` to give you what you want in a single line:

```
with open('input.txt', 'r') as f:
    nodes = [list(map(int, line.split())) for line in f]
```

An explanation of how it works:

`f.readlines()` iterates over the lines, with line endings removed

`line.split()` gives you an iterable over the space-separated characters

`map(int, ...)` does the conversion to `int` for every element

`list(...)` converts it to a list to give you a list of lists

Comment: I have never managed to look at `map` and `filter` the same after reading [Guido's plans to cut them from Py3K](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=98196).

Comment: `for line in f.readlines()` can be rewritten as `for line in f` (uses a generator)

Answer (score 0):

Just a very small note, that you don't need explicitly use `'r'`  when opening a file in read mode. That's the default mode, so there's no difference between `open('input.txt', 'r')` and `open('input.txt')`. You may as well use the latter for brevity and readability.